C++ - Function inaccessible when non-const version exists as protected
struct Fooo
{
    void func() const {}

protected:
    void func() {}
};

...

Fooo fooo;
fooo.func();

The compiler says, func is inaccessible, because it's protected. Why does it work like this? I was expecting that the non-const version will simply not be seen and the const one will be called.
I encountered this with a class giving const access to member while also having the non-const version of the function for internal usage. The other case when making a "protected mutable" base class with all non-const accessors declared protected, so one class could derive from it and keep its data not mutable by the public and other derived class made the getters abailable by bringing into public scope, like Base::getterFunc;.
class Base
{
    int a;

public:
    const auto& getA() const { return a; }

protected:
    auto& getA() { return a; }
};

class PublicAccess : public Base
{
public:
    Base::getA;
};

class KeepProtected : public Base
{

};

One specific case was Vector and NormalizedVector deriving from VectorBase. NormalizedVector can mutate its elements just not randomly by the public.
In any case, the examples are not the point, just wondering what is the logic behind this inaccessibility, when the protected version could be simply seen as not existing and the const version be chosen.

Functions with the const qualifiers can only be called on const objects.

@Someprogrammerdude Nope, it's the other way around. :)

This is simply how C++ works. Access it's checked after choosing the called function.

All member functions of a class are "seen", and tested as candidates for calling.   Once the best candidate is determined, its accessibility is checked.   If the selected function is inaccessible, then their is a diagnosable error (like you are seeing).

If the list of candidates was pruned to remove inaccessible function, then that would cause more confusion.   Imagine a class definition is edited to make a previously public function private.   Then the expectation is that the diagnostic (for non-member non-friend code calling that function) would be about an inaccessible function.   If, instead, another function was called, the code would build without error, but its behaviour could change in drastic ways that are unexpected, and [some time later when it is realised something is up] the problem can be quite difficult to find and correct.

Looking at the access specifiers is the last thing that is done. The non-const version is selected first and then the access is checked. Why is it like that? I imagine it is to simplify the process of selecting the function to call. If you think that's unreasonable then try reading the relevant portion of the standard. You'll soon realise that name lookup is a very complicated process already.

The workaround is to rename the protected func to something else, like func_ex or func_impl or func_prot for use by the protected hierarchy API, and have the const func one for the public user facing API.


I was expecting that the non-const version will simply not be seen

That's your mistake. The access specifiers (public, private, protected) do in fact not change what members are seen or considered for overload resolution.
The only effect that they have is to cause a compilation error if they are named or chosen by overload resolution. You can't use them to "hide" member functions and cause overload resolution to behave differently in different contexts. Overload resolution will work the same in all contexts. You should give functions for internal use different names than those in the external interface and not rely on overload resolution.
Or to state it a bit differently, given a program that compiles, you could replace all private and protected with public and the program would (with some small exceptions) still work exactly the same as before. They exist only to avoid making mistakes, e.g. by using a member that isn't supposed to be used externally.
